# How to return something with GroovyShell().run()?

Tags: gradle, groovy

if I run a groovy script like this from a gradle task:

```
new GroovyShell().run(file('somePath'))
```

is there a way, to return something from the script to the gradle task?

something like this

```
def file = new GroovyShell().run(file('somePath'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible to return something from a script